# ILookup with empty collections

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Is there something inherently wrong with replacing

```
IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<string>>
```

with

```
ILookup<int, string>
```

I much prefer ILookup over IDictionary because of its more 'honest' interface and immutability.

However, I discovered that ILookup is unable to hold empty collections, so keys containing empty collections are simply do not exist in it. This is problem, because I also would like ILookup to convey information about all possible keys (even though some of them might be empty), so I can go like this:

```
var statistics = from grouping in myLookup
                 select new {grouping.Key, grouping.Count()};
```

which works with dictionary of enumerables, but unfortunately does not work with ILookup. It is just impossible to have entries where grouping.Count()==0, as with IDictionary.
As John Skeet states,

> There’s one other important difference between a lookup and a dictionary: if you ask a lookup for the sequence corresponding to a key which it doesn’t know about, it will return an empty sequence, rather than throwing an exception. (**A key which the lookup does know about will never yield an empty sequence**.)

Now, what is wrong if ILookup allowed empty groupings? In order to have the best of both worlds I am about to add Filter() extension method for ILookup that does just this, but need to resolve a problem that Linq does not allow to create empty IGroupings (so I have to implement my own class), but I feel that maybe I am doing something against design principles of Linq.

[Example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b42e850a22bcea55883845e127be0b8)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: `I much prefer ILookup over Dictionary because of its more 'honest' interface and immutability.` One is an interface the other an actual class. It's not more honest and if you want an immutable dictionary use an [ImmutableDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467181(v=vs.111).aspx) or a [ReadOnlyDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712875(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm sure he meant to write `IDictionary` instead of `Dictionary`.

Comment: An `ILookup` is a *specialized* interface anyway. An `ILookup<int, string>` *is* an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, string`>>`. No groupings, no entries. Which means hodling an empty collection, ie no groupings, contradicts the interface itself

Comment: @UweKeim doesn't change the fact that `ILookup` is only an interface whose implementation isn't transparent to the end user, and *isn't* the same as an `IDictionary`. Even when compared to an IReadOnlyDictionary they have *very* different semantics

Comment: @Alexs what is the actual problem you want to solve and why do you think `ILookup` is a solution to it? ILookup has very specific semantics that have nothing to do with dictionaries or empty collections. If you care about clean interfaces, using an inappropriate interface introduces a *lot* of dirt

Comment: I've put together an example here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b42e850a22bcea55883845e127be0b8

Comment: As to why I prefer ILookup to IDictionary: it just feels right. You dont have to catch exceptions in case an entry is missing, or use ugly TryGet methods with 'out' params instead, or check for nulls that might be in place of Value instead of real collection. Not sure what is 'different semantics' you are talking about, maybe missing something here... You can perfectly use myLookup[key] to access collection of values under that key, and not groupings.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1) you could create a nice, straightforward singleton-esque EmptyLookup class as follows:

```
var empty = EmptyLookup<int, string>.Instance;

// ...

public static class EmptyLookup<TKey, TElement>
{
    private static readonly ILookup<TKey, TElement> _instance
        = Enumerable.Empty<TElement>().ToLookup(x => default(TKey));

    public static ILookup<TKey, TElement> Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }
}
```

2) You can create a singleton class for empty lookups.

```
public sealed class EmptyLookup<T, K> : ILookup<T, K> 
{
        private static readonly EmptyLookup<T, K> _instance 
            = new EmptyLookup<T, K>();

        public static EmptyLookup<T, K> Instance
        {
            get { return _instance; }
        }

        private EmptyLookup() { }

        public bool Contains(T key)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return 0; }
        }

        public IEnumerable<K> this[T key]
        {
            get { return Enumerable.Empty<K>(); }
        }

        public IEnumerator<IGrouping<T, K>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield break;
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }
then you can write code like this:

var x = EmptyLookup<int, int>.Instance;
/*The benefit of creating a new class is that you can use the "is" operator and check for type equality:*/

if (x is EmptyLookup<,>) {
 // ....
}
```

There is no wrong in keeping empty groupings is lookup, it's just that lookup does not support it because of it's nature in Linq.

You have to create an extension method by yourself.

Comment: I've put together an example here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b42e850a22bcea55883845e127be0b8

Comment: Empty lookup is not my intention, but rather a lookup allowing empty collections under some keys. Yes I know ILookup returns empty sequences if a key does not exist, but I also would like to enumerate all existing key entries in Lookup, that exist in it, but some of them might be empty